# Mongo DB query difference

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Can someone please tell me the difference b/w following two queries. Both works for me and seems to be giving correct results, but i am not sure if really there is any difference or not

Retrieve all students having scores between 80 and 95

```
     var query1 = { 'grade' : {"$gt":80}, 'grade' : {"$lt":95} };

     var query2 = { 'grade' : {"$gt":80,"$lt":95} };
```

Comment: the two options are good, but the second (query2) is the best option in terms of readability, possibly in terms of optimization too.

Comment: @innoSPG Not true. The first form will actually not work. See the detail in the answer given

Comment: Thanks for the correction Neil. I assumed that the repeating key will be taken care of; Well the implementation is not always what it should mathematically be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you will find that your first form does not actually work, even if it did for you on a minimal sample. And it will fail for a very good reason. Consider the following documents:

```js
{ "grade" : 90 }
{ "grade" : 96 }
{ "grade" : 80 }
```

If you issue your first query form you will get this for a result:

```js
{ "grade" : 90 }
{ "grade" : 80 }
```

The reason being that you cannot have the "same key" in a document like this, and one will negate the other. In this case the "right" side key takes precedence over the left key and overwrites. This is common behavior for hash or dictionary structures.

This is why the second form is required and will of course return only the document that matches the conditions that are intended to be specified.

When you have an actual case to use the same field and probably using different conditions you can use the [**`$and`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) operator. Not the best example, but just to clarify:

```js
db.collection.find({ "$and": [
     { "grade": { "$gt": 80 } },
     { "grade": { "$lt": 95 } },
]})
```

It's real purpose is to combine different conditions on the same field.

For your case though, use the second form you specified.

Comment: Thanks Neil. I like the way you explained everything. Yes i 100% agree with you that because of the data set i have, for now i am getting correct results for query one but, this approach may lead to some unexpected results in cases where you are trying to filter data from arrays etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the second query for the following reason: you query is actually a JSON. And in your first query you are providing a duplicate key (`grade`).

Nonetheless they are permitted by the [JSON RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt), however even Doug Crockford mentioned that he regrets leaving this ambiguity in the spec because it inevitably leads to all kinds of confusion.

Maybe Mongo parses it correctly right now (or may be rather in your case), but you do not know for how long will it be this way (and some other json parsers tells you that you have an error).

So the best way is to think about the first query as bad and only use second one.